# how to get data uploaded in html

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to imitate the facebook style of uploading photos. As in select multiple photos and upload and i can see the progress indicator of each and the total. However i have few basic questions:

- How to get the amount of data uploaded or remaining in comparision
  to the total data to be sent in php. For example if i am sending two
  photos say pic1.jpg and pic2.jpg of 4mb and 6mb respective. When
  uploading, i calculate progress percentage like below:
  (bytes_process/total_bytes) * 100. How do i get the bytes_progress
  value in php???
- On client side i know i need to use form data and event listener to
  "progress" of xmlhttprequest.

Other suggestion how to mock the facebook upload is welcome however please dont consider it as an answer. I NEED THE ANSWER for the above questions as well. It will help me understand few basics well

Comment: this will help u: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/04/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [upload progress session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php)

Comment: thanks a lot. damn i didn realise "ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . $_POST[ini_get("session.upload_progress.name")];" enables the
 "bytes_processed" => 57343250 in the above link. I was wondering how u get that value. Also how does "upload_progress_123" value get set, it cant be a default. where do you set session name?

Comment: hey i got it. Since it is name=value in post and get when we do
ini_get("session.upload_progress.name")=123, the session value will have 123 as suffix